# Safari - Money.js applies formatting only on first table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, currency

I am using money.js and accounting.js for formatting. The process is, when the page loads, it grabs the `#` value from the URL (if there is) and converts each value in the table row to the selected conversion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basictable1.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript" src="money.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="accounting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<!-- Below are the exchange rates and the base currency -->
<script>
fx.base = "USD";
fx.rates = {
    "EUR" : 0.745101, // eg. 1 USD === 0.745101 EUR
    "GBP" : 0.647710, // etc...
    "HKD" : 7.781919,
    "CNY" : 8000,
    "USD" : 1,        // always include the base rate (1:1)
    /* etc */
}

var symbols = {
    "EUR" : '€',
    "GBP" : '£',
    "HKD" : 'HK$',
    "CNY" : '¥',
    "USD" : '$', 
}
var currentConversion = "USD";

</script>






<h2>money.js & accounting.js</h2>
<p>On first load of the page, values are returned from the server as shown in the table in USD (US DOLLARS). They should be formatted with javascript (accounting.js) to have the correct decimals 
and the correct currency symbol ($).<br><br>
The Correct formatting is as follows: <br><br>
<u>For Column Price:</u><br>
<br>Prices below 1 should be formatted with 6 decimals (e.g. 0.123456)<br>
Prices above 1 should be formatted with 2 decimals (e.g. 1.23)<br><br>
<u>For Column Month & Column Year:</u><br>
Prices should be formatted without decimals (e.g. 98473)<br><br>
</p>

<p>When the toggle is used and a different currency is selected, money.js should be used to calculate the price from the base (USD) to the new price using the exchange rate in 
the html page. Also the numbers should be formatted correctly, and the correct symbol for the currency should be added. The value of the dropdown should also be set to the new currency. </p>

<p><a href="http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/" target="blank">money.js docs</a></p>
<p><a href="http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/" target="blank">accounting.js docs</a></p>

<div class="dropdown-currency">
  <span class="selected-currency">USD</span> <span class="arrow-down"></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">                            


        <li><a href="#USD" class="price-toggle" data-currency="usd">USD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#CNY" class="price-toggle" data-currency="cny">CNY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#EUR" class="price-toggle" data-currency="eur">EUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#GBP" class="price-toggle" data-currency="gbp">GBP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#HKD" class="price-toggle" data-currency="hkd">HKD</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="table-two-axis" class="two-axis">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>FRUITS</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>

            <th class="invisible">MONTH</th>


            <th class="invisible">YEAR</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

        <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Apples</a></td>
                <td>222.22</td>
                <td class="invisible"> 2360096267</td>
                <td class="invisible"> 21213536108</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Pears</td>
                <td>333.44</td>
                <td class="invisible"> 978984251</td>
                <td class="invisible"> 43618713955</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Oranges</td>
                <td>44.43</td>
                <td class="invisible">  259375189</td>
                <td class="invisible">2460278427</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Kiwi</td>
                <td>0.371500</td>
                <td class="invisible"> 160084682</td>
                <td class="invisible">6946057745</td>
            </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Tomatoes</td>
                <td>15.73</td>
                <td class="invisible">118967668</td>
                <td class="invisible">1474397171</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Separate this function so we can re-use it
    function formatCurrencies(desiredConversion, symbol){

        // Change selected text in the dropdown
        $('.selected-currency').html(desiredConversion);
        // Get actual array of children from table tbody : table rows
        var table = $('table tbody').children().toArray();
        // We loop through tables to actually convert each value
        table.forEach(function(tr, key){

            var tdAmount = $(tr).children('td:nth-child(3)');
            var tdMonth = $(tr).children('td:nth-child(4)');
            var tdYear = $(tr).children('td:nth-child(5)');

            // Unformat prices first to avoid NaN errors because of delimiters
            var price = accounting.unformat(tdAmount.text()); 
            var month = accounting.unformat(tdMonth.text()); 
            var year = accounting.unformat(tdYear.text()); 

            price = fx(price).from(currentConversion).to(desiredConversion);

            if(price > 1){
                // Two decimal places

                tdAmount.html(accounting.formatMoney(price, {
                    symbol: symbol,
                    format: "%s %v",
                    precision: 2
                }));
            } else {
                // Six decimal places
                tdAmount.html(accounting.formatMoney(price, {
                    symbol: symbol,
                    format: "%s %v",
                    precision: 6
                }));
            }

            month = fx(month).from(currentConversion).to(desiredConversion);
            year = fx(year).from(currentConversion).to(desiredConversion);

            tdMonth.html(accounting.formatMoney(month, {symbol: symbol, format: "%s %v", precision: 0}));
            tdYear.html(accounting.formatMoney(year, {symbol: symbol, format: "%s %v", precision: 0}));

            // Assign the new currentConversion
            localStorage.setItem('currentConversion', currentConversion);
            currentConversion = desiredConversion;
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var href = "";
        if (location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
            href = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("#") + 1)
        } else {
            href = "USD";
        }

        formatCurrencies(href, symbols[href]);


        $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e){
            // We get the value of the "data-currency" attribute of the selected item
            var desiredConversion = $(this).data('currency').toUpperCase();
            var symbol = symbols[desiredConversion]; // Access the symbol by key index of symbols object
            formatCurrencies(desiredConversion, symbol);
        })
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works for Chrome and Firefox. However it doesn't work in Safari. Is there any way I can get around this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you probably provide the `HTML` and where did you get the libraries or in the best case a demo?

Comment: @OscarJara I am using money.js and accounting.js for this. I already updated the code with HTML